# Navigation Bar not stretching full width on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, web, navigationbar

I'm building a website and I thought I would test it on my new iPad. I have a header/navigation menu on the top of the site and it renders fine on my desktop. (tested in all major browsers). However when test it on my iPad the Nav bar doesn't stretch the whole way of the screen. This also happens with the footer.

Here is the CSS code used for the bar

```
#topmenu {
margin:0 auto;
height: 85px;
background: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6384916/web/img/bg-ripple-header.png) repeat  bottom left;
width:100%;}
```

So, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Define **min-width** to your `#topmenu`. For example

```
#topmenu {
margin:0 auto;
min-width:1000px;
height: 85px;
background: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6384916/web/img/bg-ripple-header.png) repeat  bottom left;
width:100%;
}
```